# Need URL id for Facebook graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the id of the URL posted to the wall, but the documentation says I can get the id from the the url I posted, but that id isn't usable because the id IS a url? Here is the code.

Answer (score 2):

Just post to the Graph API:

```
curl -XPOST -F"id=https://your-url.com" \
            -F"scrape=true" https://graph.facebook.com
```

It should return some JSON including the ID of the url:

```
{
 "url":"https:\/\/your-url.com\/",
 "type":"website",
 "title":"https:\/\/your-url.com\/",
 "updated_time":"2011-11-14T07:05:22+0000",
 "id":"10150375340063123"
}
```