# Facebook: identify object id and type by url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get the id and type of a Facebook object based on its URL.

My goal is to identify if a certain URL is a Facebook Event (for example https://www.facebook.com/events/258629027581347).

So if I had the object-id of that object I could do the following FQL query and know that if I get a result the object is an Event:

```
select eid from event where eid = 258629027581347
```

The problem is getting the object-id based only on the URL. I do **not** want to parse the id from the URL because there is no guarantee that the format of the URL will remain the same in the future. I want to find a way to do it through one of Facebook's API's.

After searching for a while, I found the following suggestions for how to do this, but unfortunately none of them work:

1. FQL query from the `object_url` table - the query yields no results:

   `SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE url = "https://www.facebook.com/events/258629027581347"`
2. Use the graph api:

   `https://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/events/258629027581347`

   This returns a JSON object containing only the URL - no id.
3. Use the graph api with `?ids=` like this:

   `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=https://www.facebook.com/events/258629027581347`

   This returns the following JSON, also no id:

   `{
     "https://www.facebook.com/events/258629027581347": {
       "id": "https://www.facebook.com/events/258629027581347", 
       "metadata": {
         "connections": {
           "comments": "https://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/events/258629027581347/comments?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBADzSuuyJWohIwkXuvQGJUsIlSJz04J4nzKqqQXTvGiPXf4YDBPuh0rdyXgSWnWcJpN3X3GaATVLjG6UmZBiHKmcxCWwZDZD"
         }, 
         "type": "link_stat"
       }
     }
   }`

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: I also found this post, but haven't tested it yet:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8118320/319182

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't an API method at this time that takes a Facebook URL and tells you what it is. The only way to go about this is to parse the URL and look for the last element and pass this to `https://graph.facebook.com/258629027581347?metadata=1&access_token=XXXX`

It's a noble goal that you are trying to build a future-proof Facebook application, but I don't think that is a possibility at this time. The Facebook platform is still evolving. There is less of a guarantee that the api methods will remain constant than the url struture.